# Error with Reading JSON data from Brewerydb API

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am trying my first API call using JSON to collect brewery information and receive the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Brewery.Adjunct]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'message', line 1, position 11.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace Brewery
{
class Adjunct
{
    //properties
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }

    public string category { get; set; }

    public string catDisplay { get; set; }

    //create list of Adjunct objects
    public List<Adjunct> adjuncts{ get; set; }

    //address with query for all adjunct items
    const string address = "http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/?[MY KEY]/adjunct";


    //fill adjuncts with deserialized json data
    public void GetBeer(string beer)
    {
        //initialize beer list
        adjuncts = new List<Adjunct>();

        //build connection with query and return string
        //***static class Connect uses System.net to create web request and web response objects***
        string result = Connect.GetConnection(address);

        //get list of Adjunct objects
        adjuncts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Adjunct>>(result);
    }


    //get Adjunct string
    public string PrintData(string sep)
    {
        return "name: " + name + sep + "id: " + id + sep + "description: " + description;
    }


    //search adjunct by id
    public Adjunct AdjunctByID(int _id)
    {
        foreach (Adjunct ad in adjuncts)
        {
            if (_id == id)
            {
                return ad;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Do I need to use a different JSON.NET method?

Comment: It would help if you included the JSON your are trying to deserialize. But my guess would be exactly what the error message says. You are trying to deserialize a property into the list `adjucts`, but it's not an array in the JSON.

Comment: I suspect your Adjunct class is not correct. You can generate C# classes from JSON here: [http://json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com).

Comment: Here is one example:    {        id: 876,8.        name: "Acid Blend",9.        category: "misc",10.        categoryDisplay: "Miscellaneous",11.        createDate: "2013-06-14 12:19:03"12.    },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [brewerydb documentation](http://www.brewerydb.com/developers/docs-endpoint/adjunct_index) your classes should look like:

```
public class Adjunct
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string categoryDisplay { get; set; }
    public string createDate { get; set; }
}

public class AdjunctsReply
{
    public int currentPage { get; set; }
    public int numberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
    public List<Adjunct> adjuncts { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

You'd be able to deserialize the JSON like so:

```
reply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdjunctsReply>(result);
```

For example:

```
public void GetBeer(string beer)
{
    //initialize beer list
    AdjunctsReply reply;

    //build connection with query and return string
    //***static class Connect uses System.net to create web request and web response objects***
    string result = Connect.GetConnection(address);

    //get list of Adjunct objects
    reply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdjunctsReply>(result);

    foreach(var adjunct in reply.adjuncts) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(adjunct.name);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Fully working example. Just insert your key and run it as an console application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebClientDownloadMp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Insert your key here
            var key = "0000000000000000000000000000";

            var client = new WebClient();
            var reply = client.DownloadString(@"http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/adjuncts?key=" + key);
            var adjunctsReply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdjunctsReply>(reply);
            Console.WriteLine("Current page: " + adjunctsReply.currentPage);
            Console.WriteLine("Total pages: " + adjunctsReply.numberOfPages);
            Console.WriteLine("Total results: " + adjunctsReply.totalResults);
            foreach (var adjunct in adjunctsReply.Adjuncts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id {0}: {1}", adjunct.id, adjunct.name);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Adjunct
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string categoryDisplay { get; set; }
        public string createDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdjunctsReply
    {
        public int currentPage { get; set; }
        public int numberOfPages { get; set; }
        public int totalResults { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public List<Adjunct> Adjuncts { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, can the Adjunct class contain methods also, or just the properties that match the JSON object?

Comment: It can contain methods as well.

Comment: So, I need to use JSON in the AdjunctReply class?

Comment: Additional information: Error converting value "You have reached the BreweryDB.com API.  For access, check out http://www.brewerydb.com/developers" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Brewery.Adjunct]'. Path 'data', line 1, position 142.

Comment: Ehm, so you are connect to are connecting to http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/?MY KEY/adjunct for real!? You need to get a developer account and replace [MY KEY] with the key of that account.

Comment: But AdjuctReply is not an enueramted type. Should I refer to it's list of Adjuncts? Still getting above error though.

Comment: No, I have a key..should i post it? I get a success message if I leave out the JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my answer. The reply contains an enumerable list of adjuncts. If you enter the address api.brewerydb.com/v2/?YOURKEY/adjuncts in the browser, do you get a JSON response like the [documentation](http://www.brewerydb.com/developers/docs-endpoint/adjunct_index)?

Comment: I just noticed the address should be api.brewerydb.com/v2/adjuncts?key=YOURKEY

Comment: error converting value to type List<Adjunct> data, line 1, position 142...what... What does this refere to?

Comment: I added "/adjunct" instead of "/adjuncts" with an 's'.

Comment: What does this line do? [JsonProperty("data")]

Comment: It's an `NewtonSoft.Json` attribute that tells the deserializer that the Json contains a property called 'data' and that the value of that property should be put in the property Adjuncts. Documented [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_serialization_jsonproperty.htm)

Comment: This is so cool! Thank you for the lesson venerik! I am going to go kiss somebody!

Comment: Have fun but don't forget to come back to [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) B-)

Comment: Can I nest the Adjunct class into the AdjuctReply class?